# After moving to Pixel 6 Pro, some daily apps are no longer supported

Tags: applications, google-play-store, google-pixel, google-pixel-6

I've recently upgraded my phone from Pixel 3 XL to Pixel 6 Pro.
After some time, I noticed that some are apps are missing from the Pixel 6 Pro. I can't find those apps at the Google Play store, and in the web version of the Play Store it say that they are not compatible with the Pixel 6 Pro:
[image: screenshot from the Google Play store on the web]

It's probably not because of the Android version (13), because I know that these apps are available and working fine on some Pixel 5 devices running Android 13.

I thought that maybe it has to do something with the device's screen resolution or DPI/PPI, which the app might not support - but really unsure about this.

Any ideas about what could solve it, without side-loading APKs? Either from the user's perspective, or from the developer's perspective.

Comment: There are many potential reasons why an app is not available for a device. May be you should edit your question and add the PlayStore link to a few of the apps you miss. Then may be we will be able to investigate the reason.

Comment: @Robert sure, here's one of them: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.moblin.israeltrain